# Python, please help me that why my rect cant move

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to make a basic game using pygame, but the rectangle i created can not move after i press the key, please teach me how to fix it,thank you

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
class Tile:
    def __init__(self,surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 200
        self.position = (self.x, self.y)
        self.color = pygame.Color('red')
        self.speed = 5
        self.size = 30
        self.rect =        pygame.Rect(self.position[0],self.position[1],self.size,self.size)
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface,self.color,self.rect)
    def moveUp(self):
        if self.rect.top < self.speed:
            self.speed = self.rect.top
        self.y = self.y - self.speed
    def moveDown(self):
        maxBottom = self.surface.get_height()
        if maxBottom - self.rect.bottom < self.speed:
            self.speed = maxBottom - self.rect.bottom
        self.y = self.y + self.speed
    def moveLeft(self):
        if self.rect.left < self.speed:
            self.speed = self.rect.left
        self.x = self.x - self.speed 
    def moveRight(self):
        maxRight = self.surface.get_width()
        if maxRight - self.rect.right < self.speed:
            self.speed = maxRight - self.rect.right
        self.x = self.x + self.speed
    def move(self,key):
        if key == K_w:
            self.moveUp()
        if key == K_s:
            self.moveDown()
        if key == K_a:
            self.moveLeft()
        if key == K_d:
            self.moveRight()
def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(20, 20)
    surfaceSize = (500, 400)
    windowTitle = 'Pong'
    frameDelay = 0.01
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfaceSize, 0, 0)
    pygame.display.set_caption(windowTitle)
    gameOver = False
    tile = Tile(surface)
    tile.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and not gameOver:
                tile.move(event.key)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(frameDelay)
main()
```

I was trying to make a basic game using pygame, but the rectangle i created can not move after i press the key, please teach me how to fix it,thank you

Comment: Well one definite issue is `if key ==K_w:` etc.. put a print inside and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only updating your own x and y variables, and not the PyGame ones for the rect, you can fix it quickest in the draw function, but it's really an updating operation so should go in those functions:

```
def draw(self):
    self.rect.top = self.y  # You need to update the position of the rect
    self.rect.left = self.x  # and not just your own x, y variables.
    pygame.draw.rect(self.surface,self.color,self.rect)
```

Then your indentation for updating the display is off, but you need an extra line anyway:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and not gameOver:
            tile.move(event.key)
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))  # Fill the screen with black to hide old rect
    tile.draw()  # Re-draw the tile in new position
    pygame.display.update() # Update the display
```

Last thing to fix, don't use time.sleep for the frame delay, use PyGame's inbuilt clock function. Here's a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNjSyBlbl_Q&nohtml5=False

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements looks suspect to me:
if self.rect.left < self.speed

How is self.speed related to self.rect.left?

You should instead be shifting the entire rect by self.speed in the direction you want.  Try that.

I also find adding print statements throughout the code and looking at the console can help a lot.  An even better solution would be to use a debugger.

Comment: i was trying to make the rectangle not move out of the window, so if the coordinate of the rect is smaller than the speed, which will move out of the window if i continue to press the key, so i set this kind of if statement. i was used debugger, and the game could run, but it did not response if i press the key and no error displayed